# An example of unbounded operator in $\Bbb{R}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

$\Bbb{R}$ is a linear space over $\Bbb{Q}$ with infinite dimension. That means, there are unbounded operators in $\Bbb{R}$. Is there a nice example of such operator? Is there any well-known function $\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{Q}$ which is an unbouned linear operator in this space?

Comment: Generally the only situation where one can produce an explicit example of an unbounded linear functional on a normed vector space is when the space is not complete. When I say "produce an explicit example" I mean without using some nonconstructive axiom like the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "coordinate functions" for a basis of $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$ are the standard example.

On the other hand, you won't be able to construct an example without some form of Axiom of Choice. Any such unbounded operator
is a discontinuous additive function, and therefore not Lebesgue measurable; but [Solovay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solovay_model) showed that, assuming the existence of an inaccessible cardinal, there is a model of ZF (without Axiom of Choice) in which every 
set of reals is Lebesgue measurable.